# ffmpeg resize PNG image sequence using alpha padding

Tags: ffmpeg, png, resizing

I am trying to resize a sequence of PNG images using alpha padding (the images are already surrounded by alpha pixels). The following command resizes how I want, but it adds black pixels:

```
ffmpeg -i "images\test_%04d.png" -vf scale=4096:4096:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=4096:4096:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1 "images-withborder\test_%04d.png"
```

According to [ffmpeg wiki on Scaling](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling), it is only possible to pad with black pixels. Is it possible to pad with alpha pixels instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pixel has to have *some* color intensity. For transparency, what it needs is the corresponding alpha value to be zero. So modify pad to this,

```
pad=4096:4096:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=black@0
```